# Should you create a separate user for web content?

Tags: linux, security

Not so long ago I saw a colleague of mine creating a separate user on a linux for putting his web site content under this users home folder. He told me that he does so, because of security considerations. I was wondering is there really a reason for doing this? Since you can set permission of the web content folder to www-data wherever it is located?

An example:

1. Create a user "web" for web content -> $ adduser web
2. Put your web content under /home/web
3. Point your web server to /home/web/app as root folder

Comment: Most linux distributions already do this, eg. user `www-data` on Debian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using $HOME as webroot is not a good idea because most systems will create some basic files within $HOME when you create a user (ex. .profile, .bashrc,.bash_history,...)

Create a dedicated user for your webserver (ex. www-data in debian) with a normal (or no) $HOME but setup your server to use a different document root.